# Persistent Edit In Chrome DevTools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

There's an [online tool](https://pokemondb.net/tools/type-coverage) that I'd like to tweak. It depends upon a [JSON file](https://pokemondb.net/json/typechart). The easiest way for me to make the changes that I desire is to edit this JSON file directly, which I'm doing using the "Edit text" feature of Chrome DevTools. Next, I need to reload the main webpage so that it fetches the edited JSON file. Of course, this doesn't work because the webpage fetches the resource from the server. Is there any way to make the webpage temporarily load my edited JSON file?

Comment: It might be easier to develop your own extension that does this?

Comment: Like a userscript? I guess that'd work. Back to school then.

Comment: I'm not familiar with userscripts, but the chrome site has [an excellent page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview) for extension developers, and they're very easy to implement.

Comment: I might have a hack, but I need more information on where / how exactly the tool uses that JSON data. Please give me a list of reproducible steps.

Comment: The tool uses a jQuery plugin to load the JSON file from within an IIFE. It uses [`$.localDb`](https://github.com/svivian/jquery-localdb) to load the file. This plugin uses [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) to cache the data. Now that I think about it, I can manipulate the localStorage data directly. Thanks. You got me thinking and hence I was able to come up with a viable solution.